# nodejs tls session id

Tags: node.js, ssl, sessionid

I am using TLS to create session using node.js library. Node.js does it provide a way to retrieve session id of TLS connection established. It is part of SSL ctx in openssl.

Can it be done without using connect, express or geddy?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think that information is exposed from the SSL context for node connections.

You can access the node object representing the context as follows:

```
var con = tls.connect(..., ...);

con.pair.credentials.context
```

Unfortunately, the only methods available on that object are setKey, setCert, addCACert, addCRL, addRootCerts, setCiphers and setOptions.

That said, with a little bit of C++ and SSL know-how and come copy/pasting, you could probably patch node's node_crypto.cc and node_crypto.h files to add that lookup without TOO much work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the session_id but you can get the session itself for caching / resume purposes by calling `conn.getSession()` once the connection is established.