# Use of 'resumeSession' event for node's TLS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl

Node's TLS module provides a [resumeSession](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_event_resumesession) event for resuming an earlier session. Can someone show me a sample code as to how to initiate the steps on the client side?

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698737/use-of-resumesession-event-for-nodes-tls-module

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question? You want to know what has to happen client-side to make Node's TLS server emit a `resumeSession` event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to resume a TLS session on the client-side with [`tls.connect(options, [callback])`](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback). 
To make it short: You can't. You'd need to be able to send the session ID of the previous session. This is currently not implemented in Node's API.

To be a bit more sophisticated: [You could](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341786/420747).

Maybe you'd like to open an [issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues).

Comment: I mean and I quote from the official docs, I guessed supplying the session id from the session received at the server end, to the 'sessionidContext' option for tls.connect should have fired the 'resumeSession' event at the server end. Alas, I am not sure that providing the hex representation of the sessionid is the correct way..its giving an error..